# Call list of functions with different values in python3

Tags: python-3.x

What I want is a trick like (pseudocode):

```
some1 = 10
some2 = 20
magic_value = True

func_list = [ fun1(test=magic_value, some=some1), fun2(test=magic_value, some1=some1, some2=some2) ]

if not all(func_list):
  print('Test is not passed')
  return

magic_value = False
if all(func_list):
  print('Actions have been done')
```

I want to have some functions that can do a test (check if corresponding action can be done with the passed arguments) or an action accordingly some selector `test`. Those functions can have some parameters and in this example return boolean value. The number of parameters differ for each function. I want to combine those functions with their parameters to a structure to not write many code, and then call them in the test mode and in the action mode. To have a reference to some magic variable that can change value as the `test` parameter, for example. A kind of twice lazy evaluation.

Is it possible to do somehow using python3?

**Update**

My naive ugly implementation (working code):

```
class TestSwitcher():
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = bool(value)

  def setTrue(self):
    self.value = True

  def setFalse(self):
    self.value = False

  def get(self):
    return self.value


def func_combiner(func_list, test_obj):
  if not isinstance(test_obj, TestSwitcher):
    raise TypeError('test_obj should be an object of the class TestSwitcher')
  def internal():
    return [ fun(test=test_obj.get(), **kargs) for (fun, kargs) in func_list ]
  return internal


def fun1(test, arg):
  if test:
    print(f'Do a test {arg}')
  else:
    print(f'Do an action {arg}')
  return True

def fun2(test, arg1, arg2):
  if test:
    print(f'Do a test {arg1} {arg2}')
  else:
    print(f'Do an action {arg1} {arg2}')
  return True

func_list = [
  # (fun, kargs),
  (fun1, {'arg': 10}),
  (fun2, {'arg1': 20, 'arg2': 30})
]

test_obj = TestSwitcher(True)
combi_obj = func_combiner(func_list, test_obj)

test_obj.setTrue()

if not all(combi_obj()):
  print('Test is not passed')
  exit(1)

test_obj.setFalse()

if all(combi_obj()):
  print('Actions have been done')
```

Results:

```
Do a test 10
Do a test 20 30
Do an action 10
Do an action 20 30
Actions have been done
```

Comment: Hard to know exactly what you are asking, but take a look at *args and **kwargs - I suspect that will get you where you need to go. You can define your arguments as a list or a dictionary that can be dynamically changed.

Comment: @SteveJ I want to combine several functions to a structure and call them several times together changing one of the arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like that with **kargs:

```
some1 = 10
some2 = 20
magic_value = True

def fun1(**kargs):
  test = False
  res = 0
  for name, arg in kargs.items():
    if(name == "test"):
      test = arg
      continue
    if(test):
      res += arg

  return res


def fun2(**kargs):
  test = False
  res = 0
  for name, arg in kargs.items():
    if(name == "test"):
      test = arg
      continue
    if(test):
      res -= arg
  return res


func_list = [ fun1, fun2 ]

for fun in func_list:

  if(fun(test=magic_value, some=some1) < 0):
    print('Test is not passed')

  if(fun(test=magic_value, some1=some1, some2=some2) > 20):
    print('Actions have been done')
```

result:

```
Actions have been done
Test is not passed
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done an implementation, not very beautiful on my opinion:

```
class TestSwitcher():
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def setTrue(self):
    self.value = True

  def setFalse(self):
    self.value = False

  def get(self):
    return self.value


def func_combiner(func_list, test_obj):
  if not isinstance(test_obj, TestSwitcher):
    raise TypeError('test_obj should be an object of the class TestSwitcher')
  def internal():
    return [ fun(test=test_obj.get(), **kargs) for (fun, kargs) in func_list ]
  return internal


def fun1(test, arg):
  if test:
    print(f'Do a test {arg}')
  else:
    print(f'Do an action {arg}')
  return True

def fun2(test, arg1, arg2):
  if test:
    print(f'Do a test {arg1} {arg2}')
  else:
    print(f'Do an action {arg1} {arg2}')
  return True

func_list = [
  # (fun, kargs),
  (fun1, {'arg': 10}),
  (fun2, {'arg1': 20, 'arg2': 30})
]

test_obj = TestSwitcher(True)
combi_obj = func_combiner(func_list, test_obj)

test_obj.setTrue()

if not all(combi_obj()):
  print('Test is not passed')
  exit(1)

test_obj.setFalse()

if all(combi_obj()):
  print('Actions have been done')
```

Results:

```
Do a test 10
Do a test 20 30
Do an action 10
Do an action 20 30
Actions have been done
```

May be somebody can do better